# Azure Node Function w/ Eventhub output binding to dynamically routed ADX table

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-data-explorer

Having difficulties outputting from my function to an eventhub and finally into ADX *when I want to target a table to route to*. I have had no issues hitting target tables with the Node SDK via **EventHubProducerClient** in which case, you simply specify those properties next to the body of the event your sending:

```
 {
  body: {
   some:"fieldValue"
  },
  properties: {
    Table: 'table_name',
    Format: 'JSON',
    IngestionMappingReference: 'table_name_mapping'
  }
}
```

But doing this in the same manner when using the output binding documented in [Azure Event Hubs output binding for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-javascript#configuration) where the messages that I would push would take the form of the above JS object does not work. The SDK documentation is [non-helpful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/event-hubs/eventdata?view=azure-node-latest#property-details).

I can confirm that the data is in fact flowing from the Function to the Eventhub and into ADX *if and only if* I change the adx data connection for said eventhub to target a specific table (the opposite of the behavior I want) which is documented in [Ingest data from event hub into Azure Data Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-hub#target-table).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this seems so silly!

Edit: grammar

Comment: There are a few things we can check. Can you run `.show ingestion failures` to see if that shows anything. Next up I would verify if there is a Data Connection set up from your Event Hub to Azure Data Explorer for the database that you are trying to ingest into.

Answer (score 0):

The returned object is set as the data payload of the Event Hub Message that the Azure Functions runtime returns. Unfortunately, there is no way to change this from the JS Function itself.

In a C# Function you can return an [`EventData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventdata?view=azure-dotnet) object but this isn't supported in non-C# languages.

You're only option, if you need your function to be in JS, is to use the Event Hub SDK directly.

Comment: Thank you for the response - I thought I was going crazy! Do you have a documentation source for this lack of feature (sort of a weird question, I've looked everywhere myself).

If anything, I'd like to submit a change to their docs to explicitly point out this issue so that no one else goes down the silly road that I did